# Avoiding hardcoding secrets into ~/.kube/config

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, security, amazon-eks

I'd like to configure the `kubectl` tool to use the variables defined in my current shell in order to connect to the cluster, rather than pointing to the profile defined in a ~/.aws/credentials file, for security reasons.

This works with the normal `aws` command already, as well as `terraform` which is what I'm using to provision my resources.

I'm sourcing the values into my shell before running commands via the 1Password CLI tool. Is it possible to have the `kubectl` command use the values already defined in my current shell environment (currently `$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`) rather than using the configuration file?

If not, how do you typically avoid hardcoding AWS keys into local configuration files that let you connect to an EKS cluster on AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `kubectl` command is not using the aws credentials, but the context configuration in $HOME/.kube/config

You may configure the k8s context using the [aws eks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html) command which is using the env variables. btw — I suggest always providing AWS_REGION too along the credentials

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region region-code --name my-cluster
```

Then check the kubectl context, it should be configured

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```